# fatal error when using wp_list_table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, class, fatal-error

I'm in fighting with a fatal error when using wp_list_table in a class , in totally i extend the wordpress wp_list_table in a class and then include it into my plugin when i try to instance an object from it , and call the .display() function it says:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress_33/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php
>   on line 87

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 8):

I found I had to explicitly include the 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php' script

```
<?php

if(!class_exists('WP_List_Table')){
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

/**
 * Handle the admin tasks for the BHAA companies
 * @author assure
 *
 */
class MyTable extends WP_List_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WP_List_Table(this is correct) or wp_list_table??

```
class Example_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {}
```

Comment: pa na pa , yes of course i customize this plugin and use wp_list_able class form it : 
`codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table`

Comment: get_current_screen was introduced in 3.1, I guess you are using a version above that?

Comment: humm , im using , latest version of wordpress (3.3) . and i know that some functionality of this class was deprecated.and now whats the solution ?

Comment: no idea. I guess you have to debug yourself that why get_current_screen is not defined as  it should be. good luck.